# How to handle this nonlinear inequality constraint in an optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have the following non-convex constraint in variables $x \geq 0$ and $\textbf{p}$

$$ax+bx\|\textbf{p}\|^2-c \leq 0$$

where $a,b,c$ are positive constants. We can see that the above constraint does not result in a convex set. How to handle such kind of constraints in the optimization problem?

Comment: There are lots of algorithms that handle nonconvex objectives and constraints, for example using penalty or barrier functions. You're just not guaranteed to converge to the global optimum, but you will find a local optimum.

Comment: How do $x$ and $p$ enter the rest of the model? That could be important in order to see possibilities for suitable variable changes etc.

Comment: Yes. what Johan said. My first thought is to try to rewrite the problem in terms of $x^{-1}$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant you mean writing the constraint as $a+b\|\textbf{p}\|^2-cx^{-1}\leq 0$. Now this constraint becomes difference of two convex functions. I read somewhere that in this case we can leave the convex part and linearize the concave part (in this case $-c x^{-1}$). Now one more thing that is particular to this problem is that the constraint should be met with equality. So in this case $x$ cannot have a zero value so its first order Taylor expansion would suffice. Is it right thinking? Please comment. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, what I am suggesting is a change of variables $y=x^{-1}$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant what about $a+b\|\textbf{p}\|^2-cx^{-1}\leq 0$? Is it wrong? And if it is right then the idea of using first order Taylor series expansion of $x^{-1}$ is right?

Comment: It's not convex, that's the problem. And why would you use an approximation if you don't have to?

Comment: @MichaelGrant $1/x$ is not convex? Is that what you mean? I am only considering positive values of $x$ so in that case the double derivative is always $>0$.

Comment: The _constraint_ is not convex. You said yourself, it involves a difference of convex functions.

Comment: @MichaelGrant yes that is right. Thats why I am trying to use the approximation. As you mentioned that I can use $y=x^{-1}$. Although this constraint will become convex but there are other constraint which will become non-convex with using $x=y^{-1}$ so thats why I am trying to replace $x^{-1}$ with it first order Taylor expansion. Is it right thing?

Comment: There is no "right thing" when your problem is not convex, I'm afraid... It might help, it might not.

Comment: @MichaelGrant very right. So my question is "is this step wrong?"

Answer (score 1):

We have the following nonlinear constraint in $x \geq 0$ and $\mathrm y \in \mathbb R^n$

$$a x + b x \| \mathrm y \|_2^2 - c \leq 0$$

where $a, b, c > 0$ are given. Using Michael Grant's suggestion, we divide both sides by $x > 0$

$$a + b \| \mathrm y \|_2^2 - c x^{-1} \leq 0$$

Let $z := x^{-1}$. Hence, we obtain the following inequality in $\mathrm y \in \mathbb R^n$ and $z > 0$

$$(c z - a) - \mathrm y^\top \left( b^{-1} \mathrm I_n \right)^{-1} \mathrm y \geq 0$$

Since $b > 0$, we can use the Schur complement to write the inequality above as a (convex) [linear matrix inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matrix_inequality) (LMI) in $\mathrm y \in \mathbb R^n$ and $z > 0$

$$\begin{bmatrix} b^{-1} \mathrm I_n & \mathrm y\\ \mathrm y^\top & c z - a\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_{n+1}$$